# How to make a simple venn diagram for following dataset data science

Tags: data-science

```
  pyth  R spark aws excel
0   1   1   0    1   1
1   1   0   1    1   0
2   1   0   0    0   1
3   1   0   1    0   0
4   1   1   1    1   0
```

This is the data set for the skills required in DS jobs
In total there are 500 rows/Entries (Jobs).

I want to make a venn diagram, in which each skill is represented by a group.

Can someone tell me how to go about it. Searched the internet, didnt find a comprehensive solution

Answer (score 0):

I found a repository with necessary help : 
https://github.com/LankyCyril/pyvenn/blob/master/pyvenn-demo.ipynb

I though it needs sets with unique values, that is common across all of them... so I choose index, simple.

```
from venn import venn
%matplotlib inline
skills = Jobs_data[['python_yn','R_yn','spark','aws','excel']] 
skills_venn={}
for i in skills.columns :
    skills_venn[i] = set(skills[skills[i]==1].index.values)
venn(skills_venn)
```

[Resultant Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYEC6.png)
So this was the solution.